# how to get data from an id on a page Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework

i have a firebase database as follows:

[image: Table adress]

I wish to retrieve the information of this JSON on my page single address but I do not know how to do it to do it because I am new in angular and firebase. below my different codes

**Adress list html**

```
    <ion-card *ngFor="let item of items;" (click)="editItem(item.key)">
      <div><b>{{item.prenom}} {{item.nom}}</b></div>
    </ion-card>
```

**Address list .ts (method)**

```
 editItem(key){

    const UserId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

    var usersRef = firebase.database().ref('adresse');
    var adaRef = usersRef.child(UserId);
    var adaFirstNameRef = adaRef.child(key);
    var path = adaFirstNameRef.toString();
    console.log(path);

    this.router.navigate(['single-adresse/' +key]);


  }
```

how to get the data on the unique address page. if you have examples I'm interested

I can recover the JSON link from firebase thanks to the child.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch data from firebase like this

Ref : https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

```js
var usersRef = firebase.database().ref('adresse/'+UserId);
usersRef.once('value').then(snapshot=>{
   let data = snapshot.val()
   console.log(data);
   // add your login here
})
```